# Where to add code in Asp.net after build and before Run of a server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a new service and want to call that before the server starts running but after all the builds are done (like connection to cosmos db and all)

I was thinking to add it in my program.cs, static void main. But I have something like this :

```
public static void main(string [] args)
{
  CreateBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateBuilder (string[] args)
```

I saw IHostedService Interface and thought that might be a good place to add code after I build and before I run the servers.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostedservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

Any idea ?

Comment: Are you targeting .Net 5 or 6, and does a Startup.cs file exist?

Comment: how about the startup class, configure and configureServices.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Starting the `Host` will start each `IHostedService` (or `BackgroundService` which inherits from it) one at a time in the order they were registered. (`.ConfigureWebHost...` also registers an `IHostedService` to run the web server)

Comment: .Net 6 and yes I do have a startup file

Comment: My startup has following methods. `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)`. `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`